# Is there a way to have an alias contain $(!!) that is expanded when it's run?

Tags: git, bash

Or a function, or anything else, for that matter.

My use case is that I have a command that I run which will find a branch name in a git repository for me, and the only output of the command is that branch name, passable to `git checkout`.  I then type `git checkout $(!!)` in order to actually perform the checkout.  What I'd like is an alias (don't care whether it's a "real" `alias`) for `git checkout $(!!)` that actually works.

I don't want a single command that finds the branch and checks it out, as it's possible that the command I use to find the branch outputs more than one branch name, in which case I rerun it with more specific arguments.  (It's an alias for `git branch -r | cut -d '/' -f 2- | grep`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fc` built-in extracts (and by default, lets you edit) your previous command from your bash history.  Using `fc -nl -1 -1` gets back the previous command (as standard output).  Hence:

```
alias again='eval $(fc -nl -1 -1)'
```

makes the command `again` do whatever you just did again, just like `!!`.  Modifying this slightly, we get (fixed, from R. Woods):

```
alias xxx='git checkout $(eval $(fc -nl -1 -1))'
```

<s>which should do the trick (not that I have tested it).</s>  Note that this is, and must be, a bash alias, not a Git alias: Git has no access to the shell's history (except by reading the file, but that is not guaranteed to be up to date—or perhaps I should say, guaranteed *not* to be up to date, at least from the bash documentation I just checked).

Comment: So `eval git checkout $(fc -nl -1 -1)` gives me pathspec errors, because the $(fc) is expanding to the command that gives the branch name.  If I wrap that in a second $() or backticks, I get an error saying that "command branch-grep can't be found" (branch-grep is the alias mentioned in my question).  It seems like there's something preventing the subshell from evaluating aliases?  EDIT: never mind -- `git checkout $(eval $(fc -nl -1 -1))` did the trick.

Comment: @R.Woods: ah, OK, I'll update the answer.  Eval placement is always a bit tricky!